# Forbidden 403 error when attaching client certificate

Tags: asp.net, security, iis-7, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am consuming some service and to consume the service provider has given a certificate.

So I have installed the certificate on **LocalMachine** and through following code I am attaching the certificate with the web request which i am posting to get response from the web service.

```
X509Certificate cert = null;
string ResponseXml = string.Empty;

// Represents an X.509 store, which is a physical store
// where certificates are persisted and managed 
X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
X509Certificate2Collection results =
    certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName,
                                Constants.CertificateName, false);
certStore.Close();

if (results != null && results.Count > 0)
    cert = results[0];
else
{
    ErrorMessage = "Certificate not found";
    return ErrorMessage;
}
webClient.TransportSettings.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
```

This works perfectly when i run the code with ASP.net Cassini  (ASP.NET Developement Server).

But when i am hosting this code in **IIS 7.0** it give **forbidden 403** Error as response.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You should maybe try this:

winhttpcertcfg -g -c LOCAL_MACHINE\MY -s (MyCertificate) -a ASPNET

As it turns out, the user who installs the certificate is automatically 
granted access to the private key, I guess then in your case that would be you, so it works in the dev environment. When the web front end comes along, you are no longer the user, ASPNET is.